# autolaunch of application in ubuntu

Tags: linux, embedded, ubuntu-10.04, init, rc

I created the script file -

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "my application is here"
./helloworld  # helloworld is our application
```

1. after creating the script file i copied it in `init.d`
2. I gave the command `chmod +x /etc/init.d/vcc_app`  (vcc_app is the name of script which I have created)
3. Then I gave the command `ln -s /etc/init.d/vcc_app /etc/rc.d/vcc_app` (rc.d is the run level directory)

But when i reboot the board my application is not executed automatically. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: your question is potentially off-topic here on [so] (see [faq#questions]) and so I've voted for it to be migrated. I posted a brief answer to get you started, but do be prepared for this to be closed/migrated.

Comment: It is an issue of how the script is *coded* (requires "start/stop"), which makes it a programming question.  How is that off topic?

Comment: @goldilocks That's a perfectly valid shell script, programming-wise. However, it is the specs of the OS that is stopping it from being executed as desired. The question could well have been rephrased to *"how to I automatically execute my script on-boot in XYZ version of Ubuntu?"*. IMHO, that's off-topic.

Comment: @ShawnChin which makes it much the same as "How do I do this on Android?", "How do I do this in Eclipse?" "Where should I put file foo for the view in MVC framework bar?" etc. etc.  And it is not such a valid script, **init script** wise.

Comment: @goldilocks I see where you're coming from, but I'm not completely convinced. Well, we're all entitled to make our own judgement which is why close/migration is driven by votes. If I'm alone on this the the vote will eventually decay so no harm done.

Comment: How do you know it's not running?  I would suspect that it is running, but that it cannot find helloworld since it is not running in the directory you think it is, and you just aren't seeing the output and the error message.  I simple test would be to add a line like: `date > /tmp/myscript-timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

Scripts that are in `/etc/init.d` need to be [LSB-compliant](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

If you simply want to automatically run commands at the end of the boot process, try placing them in `/etc/rc.local` instead.

Comment: there is no rc.local in my rfs

Comment: I don't think any (or many) distros enforce "LSB compliance" since they tend to have there own init daemon specific schemes, but that is the general idea.  @user1415119: ubuntu's **upstart** init daemon may not use an rc.local by default but it should respect it if you create one -- or you can start reading http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Answer (score 1):

Not all linux systems use the same `init` daemon (ubuntu uses upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html), but they all use `start` and `stop` functions in the script.  Other common functions are `status` and `restart`, but again, there is no true across the board standard.  Eg:

```
!#/bin/sh

start () {
    echo "application started";
    ./helloworld  # you should use an absolute path here instead of ./
}

stop () {

}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage start|stop";
esac

exit $?
```

The last bit is a switch based on the first command line arg, since init will invoke the script `myrcscript start`.

In order to use `stop()` (and the also often useful `restart()`) you need to keep, or be able to get, the pid of the process launched by `start()`; sometimes this is done with a little "pid file" in /tmp (text file containing the pid, eg, */tmp/myscript.pid* created in start()).

The "upstart" init daemon used on Ubuntu has its own specific features, but unless you need to use them, just keep it stop/start minimal and it will (probably) work anywhere.